# How to open dialog or popup when clicking on a cell in Dojo Dgrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I want to open a dialog box when clicking on a cell.I am using dgrid/editor.

```
      editor({field: "column1",label: "col1",editor: "text",editOn: "click"})
```

I am getting text box when using the above code.I want a dialog box.Please tell me how to get a dialog box.I am using OndemandGrid with JSONReststore to display the grid.

Comment: So what you want is button to click and a dialog box will show ??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need use editor to trigger a dialog, use click event on a cell is ok:

```
   var grid = new declare([OnDemandGrid,Keyboard, Selection])({ 
        store: Observable(new Memory({data: []}))
    }, yourGridConatiner);

    grid.on(".dgrid-content .dgrid-cell:click", function (evt) {
        var cell = grid.cell(evt);
        var data = cell.row.data;

         /* your dialog creation at here, for example like below */
        var dlg = new Dialog({
            title: "Dialog",
            className:"dialogclass",
            content: dlgDiv  //you need create this div using dojo.create or put-selector
        });

        dlg.show();


    });
```

If you want show a pointer while mouse over that cell, you can style it at renderCell method with "cursor:pointer"

Comment: I have 10 columns in the grid.The event should be triggered on clicking the last column's cell.The above code triggers the event when clicking any rows.Please tell how to trigger the event only when the last column's cell is clicked?

Comment: In the selector for the delegated event handler, replace `.dgrid-cell` with a class present on cells in the desired column.  e.g. `".dgrid-content .field-column1:click"`

Comment: Yes, Ken's answer is the way to control particular column. You can put a className for your last column when you create columns, for example, you name it as "lastColumn", then change it as ".dgrid-content .lastColumn:click"

Answer (score 0):

From [the wiki](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/editor):

> `editor` - The type of component to use for editors in this column; either a string specifying a type of standard HTML input to create, or a Dijit widget constructor to instantiate.

You could provide (to `editor`) a button that pops up a dialog when clicked, but that would probably mean two clicks to edit a cell: one to focus or enter edit mode or otherwise get the button to appear and one to actually click the button.

You could also not bother with the editor plugin and attach a `click` event handler to the cell and pop up a dialog from there. You would have to manually save the changes back to your store if you went that route.

Comment: I would tend to think that the second approach here (not using `editor`) may be the more natural approach, since we're talking about an already rather indirect form of input as opposed to an actual input with a value inside the cell.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right - you could try something like this:

```
function cellFormatter1(value) {
    //output html-code to open your popup - ie. using value (of cell) 

}

......

{field: "column1",label: "col1", formatter: cellFormatter1 }
```

Comment: Adding a formatter for the sole purpose of inserting an inlined event handler is not the optimal way to do this; formatters should ideally be used for display purposes only, and even then, in cases where applying styles based on the column's class isn't sufficient.  See the previous responses.